# converting .txt files into unicode

Tags: c#, unicode

is there a way i can convert a .txt file into unicode by using c#?

Answer (score 6):

Only if you know the original encoding used to produce the `.txt` file (and that's not a restriction of C# or the .NET language either, it's a general problem).

Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to learn why "plain text" is meaningless if you don't know the encoding.

Comment: Joachim: *Fantastic* article from Joel, thanks for the link. I now have it in my armory of links to redistribute liberally to those what seem to need 'em...  Cheers. - T.J.

Answer (score 5):

Provided you're only using ASCII characters in your text file, they're already Unicode, encoded as UTF-8.

In you want a different *encoding* of the characters (UTF16/UCS2, etc), any language that supports Unicode should be able to read in one encoding and write out another.

The `System.Text.Encoding` stuff will do it as per the following example - it outputs UTF16 as both UTF8 and ASCII and then back again (code gratuitously stolen from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/File-Stream/ConvertUTF8andASCIIencodedbytesbacktoUTF16encodedstring.htm)).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test {
    public static void Main() {        
        using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("practice.txt")) {
            string srcString = "Area = \u03A0r^2"; // PI.R.R

            // Convert the UTF-16 encoded source string to UTF-8 and ASCII.
            byte[] utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(srcString);
            byte[] asciiString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(srcString);

            // Write the UTF-8 and ASCII encoded byte arrays. 
            output.WriteLine("UTF-8  Bytes: {0}",
                BitConverter.ToString(utf8String));
            output.WriteLine("ASCII  Bytes: {0}",
                BitConverter.ToString(asciiString));

            // Convert UTF-8 and ASCII encoded bytes back to UTF-16 encoded  
            // string and write.
            output.WriteLine("UTF-8  Text : {0}",
                Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8String));
            output.WriteLine("ASCII  Text : {0}",
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiString));

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8String));
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciiString));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much for ur help.i figured out i m quite illetrate in unicode and encoding stuff.
cheers :)

Comment: @intrinsic, the vast majority of people are illiterate with regards to Unicode, especially those that think they're not :-) I only discovered how really complex it is in the last couple of years (we now ship software which is localized to twenty-plus different major locales and even more minor ones).

Comment: @Pax,amazing :)
i wanted the .txt to unicode thing for my semester project(making a lexical analyizer for c#)actually we are trying many things to get the job done.thanx again

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace utf16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0], Encoding.UTF8))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(args[1], false, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do really need to change the encoding (see Pax's answer about UTF-8 being valid Unicode), then yes, you can do that quite easily.  Check out the System.Text.Encoding class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488003.aspx) about this, including a whole example:

```
   // Specify the code page to correctly interpret byte values
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(737); //(DOS) Greek code page
    byte[] codePageValues = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"greek.txt");

    // Same content is now encoded as UTF-16
    string unicodeValues = encoding.GetString(codePageValues);
```